# A rota retorna "undefined" antes de função com await acabar

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express.js

Eu tenho essa rota que faz uma chamada para o "teachersRoomsClassesController", que busca informações no banco e retorna o valor. Porém o "console.log(subjects)" está printando "undefined", e depois o "console.log(a)" no controller printa o valor esperado.
Ja tentei encapsular em uma promise o console.log mas mesmo assim não funciona. Segue abaixo o código:

Rota:

```
router.get('/', authentication.required, async (req, res) => {

    const teacher_id = req.user.teacher.teacher_id;

    const subjects = await teachersRoomsClassesController.findAllByTeacherId(teacher_id);

    console.log(subjects);
    
    const courses = await coursesController.findAllToThirds();

    res.render('grade.html', { courses });
});
```

Controller:

```
async findAllByTeacherId(teacher_id: string){

        const teachersRoomsClassesService = new TeachersRoomsClassesService();
        const subjectsController = new SubjectsController();
        const roomsController = new RoomsController();

        const teacherClasses = await teachersRoomsClassesService.findAllByTeacherID(teacher_id);


        async function getAllInformation(){
            var teacherClassesResponse = [];
            for(const TC of teacherClasses){
                const subject = await subjectsController.fyndBySubjectId(TC.subject_id);
                const room = await roomsController.findById(TC.room_id);
                teacherClassesResponse.push({
                    subject: subject,
                    room: room
                });
            }

            return teacherClassesResponse;
        };

        getAllInformation()
        .then( a => {
                console.log(a);
                console.log("controller");
                return a;
            }
        );
    }
```

Logs do servidor:

```
query: 
        SELECT * FROM teachers_rooms_classes
        WHERE teachers_rooms_classes.teacher_id = "c4a2c4a1-9572-4b7c-a722-5249cd580b0d"
undefined **// console.log da rota**
query: SELECT cod, name FROM subjects
        WHERE subjects.id = "29c16137-51c5-4e90-b932-594ed8f7ec40"
query: 
        SELECT rooms.num, rooms.period, rooms.year
        FROM rooms
        WHERE rooms.id = "464a9848-643e-4b15-85a7-fcb51d905f31"
query: SELECT cod, name FROM subjects
        WHERE subjects.id = "29c16137-51c5-4e90-b932-594ed8f7ec40"
query:
        SELECT cod, name, info
        FROM courses
        ORDER BY name ASC;
query:
        SELECT rooms.num, rooms.period, rooms.year
        FROM rooms
        WHERE rooms.id = "5f16aabc-6914-463f-9726-4fb9fdaee29e"
query: SELECT cod, name FROM subjects
        WHERE subjects.id = "29c16137-51c5-4e90-b932-594ed8f7ec40"
query: 
        SELECT rooms.num, rooms.period, rooms.year
        FROM rooms
        WHERE rooms.id = "d3c87e5c-de79-4f5f-a45c-5b1cda05dd1c"
[ **// console.log do controller**
  {
    subject: TextRow { cod: '4863', name: 'ECONOMIA BRASILEIRA CONTEMPORANEA' },
    room: TextRow { num: '31', period: 'NOTURNO', year: '1°' }
  },
  {
    subject: TextRow { cod: '4863', name: 'ECONOMIA BRASILEIRA CONTEMPORANEA' },
    room: TextRow { num: '1', period: 'INTEGRAL', year: '1°' }
  },
  {
    subject: TextRow { cod: '4863', name: 'ECONOMIA BRASILEIRA CONTEMPORANEA' },
    room: TextRow { num: '32', period: 'NOTURNO', year: '1°' }
  }
]
controller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O certo seria chamar getAllInformation() com await, em vez de usar a sintaxe de promessas. Fica mais limpo (o código da promessa simplesmente vai em seguida).

Outra opção seria fazer "return getAllInformation()..." para que findAllByTeacherId() retorne uma promessa, que vai ser corretamente manipulada pelo await da rota.

Comment: Obrigado funcionou corretamente.